# Javascript: 2D Platformer, Point/Line collision, Dealing With Decimals

Tags: javascript, 2d, collision-detection

I am making a 2D game where the player object is a rectangle and the platforms are lines.
The player object has two points, the bottom left point, and the bottom right point.

When either of these points intersects with a line, a collision should occur.

I have this working using a function similar to this one here:
http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/line-point.php

When I move the player 1 pixel at a time, the function works well.

The problems start to arise when I start moving the player in directions that involve decimals.
Looks like the player moves right past the line so that collision never occurs.

The documentation I linked mentions adding a buffer, but no buffer I added made any sort of acceptable response.

Does anyone know of some documentation, or examples of point/line collision that takes decimals into account?

Edit 1:
Ive been messing around with moving the player up and down with decimal places, but doing collision testing by rounding the decimal movement into the nearest whole number and reacting based on that. Still not much luck but I think i'm on to something...

```
export { movement }

import { players } from '../modules/init_data.js';
import { platforms } from '../modules/init_data.js';
import { downPressed, upPressed, leftPressed, rightPressed, spacePressed } from './init_listener.js';

var main_player;
var leftShoeX;
var leftShoeY;
var rightShoeX;
var rightShoeY;

function movement() {
    main_player = players[0];
    leftShoeX = main_player.rectx;
    leftShoeY = main_player.recty + main_player.height;
    rightShoeX = main_player.rectx + main_player.width;
    rightShoeY = main_player.recty + main_player.height;

    if(leftPressed) {
        main_player.rectx -= 1;
    }
    if(rightPressed) {
        main_player.rectx += 1;
    }

    // go down
    if (downPressed) {
        var tempy1 = leftShoeY;
        var tempy2 = rightShoeY;
        var allowedMovement = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < main_player.speed; j++) {
            var collision1 = collision_detection(leftShoeX, (tempy1 + 1))
            var collision2 = collision_detection(rightShoeX, (tempy2 + 1))
            if (!collision1 || !collision2) {
                allowedMovement++
                tempy1++;
                tempy2++;
                if (allowedMovement == main_player.speed) {
                    main_player.recty += main_player.speed;
                }
            } else {
                main_player.recty += allowedMovement;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (spacePressed && !main_player.jumping) {
        main_player.jumping = true;
        main_player.velY += main_player.speed * 2;
    }

    if (main_player.jumping) {
        main_player.velY -= main_player.gravity;

        //up or down
        var direction = Math.sign(main_player.velY)
        //up
        if (direction == 1) {
            var tempy1 = Math.round(leftShoeY);
            var tempy2 = Math.round(rightShoeY);
            var allowedMovement = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < main_player.velY; j++) {
                var collision1 = collision_detection(leftShoeX, (tempy1 + direction))
                var collision2 = collision_detection(rightShoeX, (tempy2 + direction))
                //console.log(collision1)
                if (!collision1 || !collision2) {
                    allowedMovement++
                    tempy1++;
                    tempy2++;
                    //console.log(allowedMovement, Math.round(main_player.velY))
                    if (allowedMovement == Math.round(main_player.velY)) {
                        main_player.recty -= (main_player.velY * direction);
                        //main_player.jumping = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    main_player.recty += (allowedMovement * direction);
                    //main_player.jumping = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //down
        if (direction == -1) {
            var tempy1 = Math.round(leftShoeY);
            var tempy2 = Math.round(rightShoeY);
            var allowedMovement = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j > -main_player.maxVelY; j--) {

                var collision1 = collision_detection(leftShoeX, (tempy1 + direction))
                var collision2 = collision_detection(rightShoeX, (tempy2 + direction))

                if (!collision1 || !collision2) {

                    allowedMovement--
                    tempy1-- ;
                    tempy2--;
                    
                    //console.log(tempy2)
                    //console.log("allowed",allowedMovement)
                    if (allowedMovement == Math.round(main_player.velY)) {
                        //console.log(main_player.velY * direction)
                        main_player.recty += ((Math.round(main_player.velY) * direction));
                        console.log("butt1")
                        //main_player.jumping = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(allowedMovement)
                    main_player.recty -= (allowedMovement * direction);
                    //main_player.jumping = false;
                    console.log('butt2')
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function collision_detection(px, py) {
    var detection;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < platforms.length; i++) {
        px = px;
        py = py;
        var x1 = platforms[i].startx
        var y1 = platforms[i].starty
        var x2 = platforms[i].endx
        var y2 = platforms[i].endy
        var hit = linePoint(x1, y1, x2, y2, px, py);
        if (hit) {
            detection = true;
        } else {
            detection = false;
        }
    }
    return detection;
}

// LINE/POINT
function linePoint(x1, y1, x2, y2, px, py) {

    var d1 = Math.hypot(px - x1, py - y1);
    var d2 = Math.hypot(px - x2, py - y2);
    var lineLen = Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2);

    var buffer = 0.1;

    if (d1 + d2 >= lineLen - buffer && d1 + d2 <= lineLen + buffer) {
        //main_player.velY = 0;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the lines at various angles or just vertical and horizontal?

Comment: Vertical and horizontal, but at some point I’ll need to add slopes.

Comment: Well the issue wouldn't be decimals vs whole numbers. Likely the algorithm you cite just doesn't work properly. Now so long as the lines (and lines of the rectangle) are not at angles, you can use a simple rectangular union algorithm.

Comment: But i feel this is an XY problem because in a 2D platform game, there is generally a "game grid" where the UI stuff like drawing to the screen would not be the domain of collision detection. The game grid would be.